# How to get an script from an endpoint and use it as request response?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, http, fetch

Im working on a project that we need to consume a script from an endpoint. Yes, the API that we will consume is built for the web. So, the thing is that the endpoint returns a script, which is a self-invoking function that sets a variable. The request content-type header is application/javascript and I would like to get that result from the endpoint and use that variable in my application.

I will give a more straightforward example.

Lets suppose we have the following script:

```
const Script = (() => {
  return {
    some: "method",
    another: "method",
  };
})();
```

That script is returned from an endpoint to be used in a web browser, like so.

```
<script src="https://example.com/index.js"></script>
```

But I would like to get that script/variable to use in my React Native application, like so.

```
fetch("https://example.com/index.js", { method: "GET" }).then((response) => {});
```

And here is the problem, the response to that request is not what I need. I can convert it to a Blob, but how could I parse that Blob to a js function or something like that?

Comment: [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) should work in your case. Be aware of the risks when invoking scripts like this, see [Never use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was accomplished by using [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) that internally uses [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

As the script returned is a `Blob`, that is stored in the request result (in my case it was inside `_bodyBlob`, but I suppose that it can vary depending on the backend), I could convert that `Blob` into a string, and there is some ways to do that. The way I did was by creating a `Response` instance using my `Blob` and after that use the `text` method inside that.

With the string loaded, the script itself is a self-invoking function that was setting a variable, so I needed to edit the string to create a function that returns that variable that was being defined.

After that, I just need to create a function and execute it to get the desired object back into a variable.

```
fetch("https://example.com/index.js", { method: "GET" }).then((response) => {
  new Response(response._bodyBlob).text().then((text) => {
    const modifiedString = `${text}; return Script`;

    const scriptObject = new Function(modifiedString)();
    ...
  });
});
```